# Jest Testing with Bazel Throws "Module ts-jest in the transform option was not found"

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, bazel, monorepo

I have a working Bazel [BUILD](https://github.com/flolude/minimal-bazel-monorepo/blob/443604baf8ba1d8234f232eecb031ff561ae2bd7/services/server/src/BUILD) file that looks like this:

```
package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

load("@io_bazel_rules_docker//nodejs:image.bzl", "nodejs_image")
load("@npm_bazel_typescript//:index.bzl", "ts_library")

# TODO run jest tests and stop build if test not passes
# TODO also run tests from dependent packages
load("@lbm//:jest.bzl", "jest_test")
jest_test(
    name = "test",
    srcs = glob(
        include = ["**/*.ts"],
    ),
    jest_config = "@lbm//:jest.config.js",
    deps = [
        "//packages/enums/src:lib",
        "//packages/hello/src:lib",
        "@npm//faker",
        "@npm//@types/faker",
        "@npm//express",
        "@npm//@types/express",
        "@npm//jest",
        "@npm//ts-jest",
        "@npm//@types/jest",
    ],
)

ts_library(
    name = "lib",
    srcs = glob(
        include = ["**/*.ts"],
        exclude = ["**/*.spec.ts"]
    ),
    deps = [
        "//packages/enums/src:lib",
        "//packages/hello/src:lib",
        "@npm//faker",
        "@npm//@types/faker",
        "@npm//express",
        "@npm//@types/express",
    ],
)

nodejs_image(
    name = "server",
    data = [":lib"],
    entry_point = ":index.ts",
)

load("@io_bazel_rules_docker//container:container.bzl", "container_push")

container_push(
   name = "push_server",
   image = ":server",
   format = "Docker",
   registry = "gcr.io",
   repository = "learning-bazel-monorepo/server",
   tag = "dev",
)
```

Building the `server` works fine. But running the `test` fails.

When I run `bazel test //services/server/src:test`, I get the following output:

```
INFO: Analyzed target //services/server/src:test (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 test target...
FAIL: //services/server/src:test (see /home/flolu/.cache/bazel/_bazel_flolu/698f7adad10ea020bcdb85216703ce08/execroot/lbm/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/testlogs
/services/server/src/test/test.log)
Target //services/server/src:test up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/services/server/src/test_loader.js
  bazel-bin/services/server/src/test.sh
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.947s, Critical Path: 0.72s
INFO: 2 processes: 2 linux-sandbox.
INFO: Build completed, 1 test FAILED, 2 total actions
//services/server/src:test                                               FAILED in 0.1s
  /home/flolu/.cache/bazel/_bazel_flolu/698f7adad10ea020bcdb85216703ce08/execroot/lbm/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/testlogs/services/server/src/test/test.log

INFO: Build completed, 1 test FAILED, 2 total actions
```

and the `test.log` file has to following content:

```
exec ${PAGER:-/usr/bin/less} "$0" || exit 1
Executing tests from //services/server/src:test
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
● Validation Error:

  Module ts-jest in the transform option was not found.
         <rootDir> is: /home/flolu/.cache/bazel/_bazel_flolu/698f7adad10ea020bcdb85216703ce08/sandbox/linux-sandbox/3/execroot/lbm/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/services/server/src/test.sh.runfiles/lbm/external/lbm

  Configuration Documentation:
  https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration.html
```

So it seems as if something with `ts-jest` is not working. When running `jest` manually, I don't get any errors.

My `[jest.config.js][2]` in the root of the project looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  roots: ['<rootDir>/services/server/src', '<rootDir>/packages/hello/src'],
  testMatch: ['**/__tests__/**/*.+(ts|tsx|js)', '**/?(*.)+(spec|test).+(ts|tsx|js)'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$': 'ts-jest',
  },
};
```

You can try it yourself by cloning this repo: https://github.com/flolude/minimal-bazel-monorepo

## Update 1

I've tried to implement the original Answer from [@Charlie OConor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59640698/8586803), but then I get this error:

```
services/server/src/util.spec.ts:1:21 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './util'.

1 import { add } from './util';
                      ~~~~~~~~
```

That is why I added the `util.ts` file to the `srcs` like this:

```
srcs = glob(
    include = ["**/*.ts"],
),
```

But then I get this error:

```
ERROR: /home/flolu/Desktop/minimal-bazel-monorepo/services/server/src/BUILD:33:1: in args attribute of nodejs_test rule //services/server/src:test: label '//services/server/src:test_lib.js' in $(location) expression expands to more than one file, please use $(locations //services/server/src:test_lib.js) instead.  Files (at most 5 shown) are: [services/server/src/index.js, services/server/src/util.js, services/server/src/util.spec.js]. Since this rule was created by the macro 'jest_test', the error might have been caused by the macro implementation
ERROR: Analysis of target '//services/server/src:test' failed; build aborted: Analysis of target '//services/server/src:test' failed; build aborted
INFO: Elapsed time: 4.487s
INFO: 0 processes.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Edit Real Issue

I took a second look. Leaving the bellow answer since I think it has useful stuff in it. Your version of `build_bazel_rules_nodejs` was rather old. Update to the newest version `1.01`. You were on version `0.42.2` which I think has some weird ways it handles npm dependencies.

```
http_archive(
    name = "build_bazel_rules_nodejs",
    sha256 = "e1a0d6eb40ec89f61a13a028e7113aa3630247253bcb1406281b627e44395145",
    urls = ["https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_nodejs/releases/download/1.0.1/rules_nodejs-1.0.1.tar.gz"],
)
```

Also update the `"@bazel/typescript": "^1.0.1",` in your package.json since they need to be in sync. There are some other breaking changes between the other libs you are using in the repo. I got it to work by commenting out all the docker and other stuff that wasn't relevant. It shouldn't be too hard to update those.

## Original Answer

Probably not the answers you're looking for, but you probably don't need `ts-jest`. Its job is to make your life easier not having a separate compile step you need to coordinate before running a test. Great if your running scripts form a `package.json` but you have bazel which is all about defining the dependency graph. This makes it easy to create a `ts_library` for your test then depend on it, well the javascript output in `jest_test`

Add another `tsconfig.test.json` with

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "lib": ["jest"]
}
```

This will have it typecheck correctly with all the jest stuff, `describe()`, `it()`, etc.

To compose to `tsconfigs.json` use `ts_config` so place this in `/BUILD`

```
load("@npm_bazel_typescript//:index.bzl", "ts_config")
ts_config(
    name = "tsconfig.jest.json",
    src = "tsconfig.test.json",
    deps = [
        ":tsconfig.json",
    ],
)
```

Then create the `ts_library` for your test and define the javascript output to use in `jest_test`

```
load("@npm_bazel_typescript//:index.bzl", "ts_library")
ts_library(
    name = "test_lib",
    srcs = ["util.spec.ts"],
    # References the test tsconfig
    tsconfig = "//:tsconfig.jest.json",
    deps = [
        "//packages/enums/src:lib",
        "//packages/hello/src:lib",
        "@npm//faker",
        "@npm//@types/faker",
        "@npm//express",
        "@npm//@types/express",
        "@npm//cors",
        "@npm//@types/jest",
    ],
)

filegroup(
    name = "test_lib.js",
    srcs = [":test_lib"],
    output_group = "es5_sources",
)

load("@lbm//:jest.bzl", "jest_test")
jest_test(
    name = "test",
    srcs = [
        ":test_lib.js",
    ],
    jest_config = "@lbm//:jest.config.js",
    deps = [
        # UPDATE HERE
        ":lib",
        # END UPDATE 
        "//packages/enums/src:lib",
        "//packages/hello/src:lib",
        "@npm//faker",
        "@npm//express",
        "@npm//jest",
    ],
)
```

These rules are kinda boiler paltey so you could wrap them up into gen rules.

I did pull your code and have no idea why you aren't able to source `ts-node`. You can even import it in `jestconfig.js`. Not that you want to but it shows that the dependency is there. My assumption is there is an underlying issue with around `jest` or `ts-jest`, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: That looks great. But I get another error, now (see updated question). Can be reproduced by running `bazel test //services/server/src:test` on the latest commit

Comment: yes, both in the WORKSPACE file and the npm package

Comment: Oh sorry there is an issue in my posts `:test_lib` need to depend on `:lib` so it know the types correctly. I'll update and comment the change.

Comment: It worked! But I get the same error if I add a second `.spec.ts` file. So it basically only works with one `.spec.ts`. You'll get the bounty if you show me how to add multiple `specs` to :)

Comment: Seems to work by updating `jest.bzl` to use `locations` instead of `location`

```
    for src in srcs:
        args.extend(["--runTestsByPath", "$(locations %s)" % src])
```

also seem to be issues loading some jsDom dependencies so I had to update jest config run in a node environment.   

```
module.exports = {
  testMatch: ['**/__tests__/**/*.+(ts|tsx|js)', '**/?(*.)+(spec|test).+(ts|tsx|js)'],
  testEnvironment: "node",
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Changing `location` to `locations` did the trick

Comment: I would be really glad if you would take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59688605

Comment: You said: "These rules are kinda boiler paltey so you could wrap them up into gen rules."... is there any documentation on how to do this?